# How to include static information in logging with Log4j or similar?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

We have an application where a log message without the context in which it was run (i.e. the database) does nearly never make sense. The information is always available, but it is quite cumbersome to include it everywhere by hand. Is there a more elegant way of doing it?

I was thinking along the lines of implementing a wrapper around logging that always includes the information. I have tried it, but I'd like the LogFactory (either slf4j or Log4j) to pick this class by default, and I don't know how to do that...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at the [`NDC`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html) or [`MDC`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html) [classes](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/NDCvsMDC). You can push context information on the stack and include this automatically in your log messages.

You can find a small example [here](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/11/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code/).

In your [`PatternLayout`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html), use `'%x'` to log `NDC` information and `'%X'` for `MDC`.

Comment: MDC is part of the SLF4J as well.

Answer (score 0):

For log4j, create a class extending from PatternLayout to create your own layout.